# CSS animation not running or running endlessly

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to make a menu which opens or closes when clicked (tapped). I am applying these CSS classes to a `div` from JS depending on whether the menu is open or closed.

```
@keyframes open {
    from { 
            width: 3em; 
            left: calc(100vw - 3em);
        }
    to {
            left: calc(100vw - 15em);
            width: 15em; 
        }
}

.menu-open {
        width:  15em;
        left: calc(100vw - 15em);
        animation-name: open;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-direction: normal;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

    .menu-close {
        width: 3em;
        left: calc(100vw - 3em);
        animation-name: open;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-direction: reverse;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
```

And here is the React code of the component (it receives a prop named `menuOpen` to decide which class to apply):

```
class MenuButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);

        this.state = { className: 'menubutton' }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.menuOpen)
            this.setState({ className: 'menubutton menu-open' });
        else
            this.setState({ className: 'menubutton menu-close' });
    }

    buttonClick() {
        this.props.onMenuButtonClick();        
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className={ this.state.className } onClick={ this.buttonClick }>
                <i className="fa fa-1x fa-cogs"></i>
                </div>
                );
    }
}
```

I am not using the `animation` shorthand to see what I am doing, and I didn't specify `-webkit-` and `-o-` lines because I first want to see it working.

So the problem is that either the animation starts, but repeats endlessly (this is the current version) or if I set `animation-iteration-count` to 1, it runs only once, and never again, the menu gets switched instead of being animated.

Is there a way to tell CSS to stop the animation at the last keyframe or to reset the counter when it's done? Isn't `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` supposed to stop it?

Comment: You need [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Comment: I have @keyframes, just didn't include in the snippet. I'll add them right away.

Comment: Post the complete code please

Comment: Added the JS code.

Comment: why do you have this code  this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this); on 4th line?

Comment: So that buttonClick() will get "this".